# Error on running safeFactory.deploySafe({ safeAccountConfig })

Tags: safe-core

```
const provider = new ethers.JsonRpcProvider('https://rpc.ankr.com/eth_goerli')
const owner1Signer = new ethers.Wallet(process.env.OWNER_1_PRIVATE_KEY!, provider)
const owner2Signer = new ethers.Wallet(process.env.OWNER_2_PRIVATE_KEY!, provider)
const owner3Signer = new ethers.Wallet(process.env.OWNER_3_PRIVATE_KEY!, provider)

const ethAdapterOwner1 = new EthersAdapter({
    ethers,
    signerOrProvider: owner1Signer
})

const safeApiKit = new SafeApiKit({
    chainId: 5n
})

const safeFactory = await SafeFactory.create({ ethAdapter: ethAdapterOwner1 })

const safeAccountConfig: SafeAccountConfig = {
    owners: [
        await owner1Signer.getAddress(),
        await owner2Signer.getAddress(),
        await owner3Signer.getAddress()
    ],
    threshold: 2,
    // ... (Optional params)
}
const safeSdkOwner1 = await safeFactory.deploySafe({ safeAccountConfig })
```

**on running above code i am getting this error**

```
 error: {
      code: 3,
      message: 'execution reverted: Create2 call failed',
      data: '0x08c379a000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000013437265617465322063616c6c206661696c656400000000000000000000000000'
    },
    payload: {
      method: 'eth_estimateGas',
      params: [Array],
      id: 18,
      jsonrpc: '2.0'
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Without more context it is difficult to help you debug your code, however the problem might come from the fact the `goerli` was deprecated and should not be used anymore.

If the problem persists on other networks, you can have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74160798/why-would-create2-revert) to see the kinds of reasons why a `CREATE2` call might fail.

Hope it helps, Louis